# Is there anyway to convert a list into a variable for use as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, list, variables, dictionary

So I have a list that holds a set of alphabetical values, that are names in a dictionary, for example:

```
['H', 'I', 'B']
```

Where the individual variable names are keys that i am using in a dictionary, but my problem is, the list of HIB together represents another variable, that i wish to define in the dictionary as a keyword of HIB.  So my question is, how do i convert this list into a variable, preferably:

```
nodeName = 'HIB'
```

So I can then assign it a key in my dictionary using:

```
Tree[nodeName] = ...
```

Because obv. you cannot call lists in dictionaries.

thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can't use a list as a key in a dictionary, but you could use a tuple. This might help if some of the names end up being more than one letter (for example, `['HQ', 'I', 'B']`: `"HQIB" would be ambiguous but `('HQ', 'I', 'B')` would not.)

Comment: @Sean you can use a tuple as key in a dictionary

Comment: ahhh, i did not know dictionaries can use tuples, that is very helpful, and actual solves my problem, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> ''.join(['H', 'I', 'B'])
'HIB'
```

or you can convert it to a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(['H', 'I', 'B'])
```

or generally

```
>>> tuple(li)
```

which can be used as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_list = ['H', 'I', 'B']
"".join(my_list)
>> 'HIB'
```

The better approach, as suggested by others is to use a `tuple`:

```
my_list = ['H', 'I', 'B']
tuple(my_list)
>> ('H', 'I', 'B')
```

This will resolve the ambiguity when trying to decide whether `'HIB'` was created from `['H', 'I', 'B']` or from `['HI', 'B']`